# UITextFieldで日本語入力した時の変換対象の範囲を示す背景色を変更したい

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Xcode9
Objective-c
iOS 10.3.3
iPad用アプリを開発しています。

### 概要

UITextFieldで、"日本語かな"や"日本語ローマ字"キーボードを使用して文字を入力した場合の変換対象の範囲を示す背景色を変更したいのですが方法はあるのでしょうか？

tintColorプロパティをいじっても変化しませんでした。

### 画像

"よいてんき"の部分の薄い青色部分のことです。[image: テスト]

### UITextFieldを初期化している箇所

```
-(void)setup
{
    UITextField* tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 200, 20)];
    tf.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tf.markedTextStyle = @{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]};
    [self.view addSubview:tf];
}
```

Comment: Xcode 9.2beta, iOS11.0.1, iPad5では期待した動作となりました。

Comment: どうやらiOS10.3.3では動作せず、iOS11以降であれば正常に動作するようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

変換中のテキストは`markedText`と呼ばれ、その文字色やフォント、背景色は`markedTextStyle`で変更できます。

```
textField.markedTextStyle = @{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]};
```

上記のようにすると、変換中の背景色が赤になります。

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614500-markedtextstyle

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかし、`textField.markedTextStyle = @{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]};`を追記してみましたが、色は変わりませんでした。

Comment: `textField`が`nil`だったりしませんか？それをチェックしてもダメだったら質問文を編集してコードを載せてください。何かが間違ってます。

Comment: `textField`は`nil`ではありませんでした。コードを追記しました。

Comment: sdkの不具合? [リンク](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976216/uitextview-not-saving-markedtextstyle-uitextinput-protocol)

Comment: 私の環境では同じコードで期待した通りに動いてますね。。。何かがおかしいのだと思いますが、これ以上はわかりません。

Comment: そうですか...。ちなみに期待した通りに動いているとのことですが、参考までにXcodeのバージョン、iOSのバージョン、端末(iPad Pro等)を教えていただけませんか？

Comment: Xcode 9.1 (9B55)、iOS 11.1、10.5-inch iPad Proで確認しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。迅速に対応していただき非常に助かりました。引き続き調査してみます。